# Intersection with N matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, intersection

I have a matrix `IntialMat`, and I have a structure with N other matrices. I want to have the indices of the matrices that intersect with a least one element of the matrix `IntialMat`. How can I do that in MATLAB?

For example InitialMat=[2, 5, 88; 55 63 4]
And structure MatriciesStor have N matrices :

```
Mat1=[1, 55,12; 45 78]
Mat2=[12, 14; 42,165]
Mat3=[2,18,11; 13,80; 10, 99]
.
.
.
.
.
.
MatN=[4, 77;63,20]
```

The result that I want is the value of the intersection and the name
of the matrice or its index:
the value 2 with Mat3 (index 3)
The value 4 with MatN (index N)

Comment: Did you try the function `intersect`? Please show us where your difficult is, it makes it easier to write an answer for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes the function intersect gives a result but when I use it I hav to cite all my matrcies in the function, but I can't do that since the nmber of matricies N is very high ( 3000 for example).

Comment: _"can't do that since the nmber of matricies N is very high"_ Why weren't you thinking the same thing when _defining_ these 3000 matrices?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi , because I'am obliged to work with a STANDAR DATASET that Have this high number of matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the matrices like this:

```
IntialMat = randi(100, 3);
for i = 1:10
    MatriciesStor{i} = randi(100, 3);
end

% Now compare all Mats against IntialMat
for i = 1:10
    inter = intersect(MatriciesStor{i},IntialMat);
    if ~isempty(inter)
        fprintf("\nMatrix %d has intersections: %d", i, inter);
    end
end
fprintf("\n");
```

which gives something like:

```
Matrix 1 has intersections: 18 
Matrix 2 has intersections: 46 
Matrix 3 has intersections: 18 38 
Matrix 7 has intersections: 79 
Matrix 8 has intersections: 51 
Matrix 9 has intersections: 75
```